# I am curious about javascript destructuring

Tags: javascript, syntax, destructuring

The destructuring is one of the javascript syntax

This have been used like this.

```
const obj = { a: { A: 1, B: 2 } };
const { a } = obj // this is obj.a
const { B } = a // this is obj.a.B
```

the thing that I want to know is destructuring can save memory?

Comment: Why would it save memory? More like an easy way to reference properties instead of doing it in multiple lines/

Comment: You'll have to ask the browser makers this, since it'll depend on how the engine they use handles destructuring.

Comment: then, Is destructuring for readability only?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. It simplifies defining variables whose value is something inside the array or object. I doubt that it saves memory, but I don't know that.

Comment: why should it? why does that matter?